# Vanilla ES6 Todo/Task List with LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, to-do-list

I'm making a simple todo list app with ES6. I'm looking for some feedback on the code, I feel like there is some improvement possible. Maybe there is a better way to attach eventListeners to input and button, but to keep in mind they have to be set not just when a new element is added but on window load when the items from localStorage are retrieved. I tried to keep it short as best I could.

```js
import TaskItem from './TaskItem'; //constructor for id, title, and completed boolean
import * as helpers from './Helpers'; //two extra methods

export default class TaskList {

    constructor()
    {
        this.inputField= document.getElementById('task-input');
        this.addButton = document.getElementById('add-task');
        this.tasksElem = document.getElementById('tasks');
        this.tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userTasks')) || [];

        this.displayTasks()
        this.initializeEventListeners()

    }

    initializeEventListeners()
    {
        this.tasksElem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const taskId = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');

            switch (event.target.localName) {
                case 'button':
                    this.removeTask(taskId);
                    break;
                case 'input':
                    this.toggleCompleted(taskId);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        })


        this.addButton.addEventListener('click', this.addNewTask.bind(this))

    }

    addNewTask()
    {
        const newTaskTitle = this.inputField.value.trim();

        if (newTaskTitle)
        {
            let newTaskID = helpers.getRandomId().toString(); //still need to check if id exists
            const newTask = new TaskItem(newTaskID, helpers.htmlEscape(newTaskTitle))
            this.tasks.push(newTask)
            this.inputField.value = '';
            this.saveTasks()
            this.displayTasks()
        }

    }
    
    removeTask(idToRemove)
    {
        this.tasks = this.tasks.filter((task) => {
            return task.id !== idToRemove
        });

        this.saveTasks()
        this.displayTasks()
    }
    toggleCompleted(idToToggle)
    {
        this.tasks.forEach((task)=>{
            if (task.id === idToToggle) {
                task.completed = !task.completed;
            }
        })

        this.saveTasks()
        this.displayTasks()
    }

    saveTasks()
    {
              localStorage.setItem('userTasks',JSON.stringify(this.tasks));
    }


    displayTasks()
    {
        this.tasksElem.innerHTML = this.tasks.reduce((acc, task) => {
            return acc + this.returnTaskTemplate(task)
        },'');

    }


    returnTaskTemplate(task)
    {
        return `<li data-id="${task.id}">
                   <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" ${task.completed ? 'checked' : ''}>
                   <label >${task.title}</label>
                   <button>Remove</button>
                </li>`;
    }
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a better extensibility (for example, easy to add new actions) and to get the `taskId` only if I’m going to use it.

```
initializeEventListeners() {
    const actions = {
        button: 'removeTask',
        input: 'toggleCompleted'
    };

    this.tasksElem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const action = actions[event.target.localName];
        if (action) {
            const taskId = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');
            this[action](taskId);
        }
    })

    this.addButton.addEventListener('click', this.addNewTask.bind(this))
}
```